# File transformation in Azure Release pipeline

Tags: xml, azure, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a **custom **config file created in my ASP .NET project, that looks as shown below. The problem with this config file is, I can't make use of the **Library --> Variable group** inorder to transform the parameters based on the environment. I wonder if I can do this without creating another build & deploy on top of the original project for this custom config file.

Custom Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings name="Default">
        <key name="ConnectionName">TestProject</key>
        <key name="SharePointConnection">Data Source=CustomerData;Initial Catalog=Userdata;User ID=Userdata;Password=Something123;Integrated Security=False;Connect Timeout=60;</key>
        <key name="SharePointWebUrl">https://google.com/sites/CustomerData/</key>
        <key name="SharePointWebServiceUrl">https://google.com/sites/CustomerData/Sharepointvice.asmx</key>
        <key name="Enabled">True</key>
    </appSettings>
    <appSettings name="Product">
        <key name="ConnectionString">Integrated Security=False;Data Source=ProductList;Initial Catalog=PDL;User ID=PDLUser;Password=Something123;</key>
        <key name="CommandTimeoutSeconds">60</key>
        <key name="ProductList">54544,444545,54545245,665656565,5454545,4</key>
        <key name="CustomerIDList"/>
        <key name="DaysBack">1</key>
        <key name="PreparedFor">Austin</key>
        <key name="Schema">Something</key>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

With the above structure, I can't use the Variable library because it needs a name and a value unlike in the regular Config files.

[image: Sample Variable Library]

Because the regular structure of the config file should look as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ConnectionName"
             Value="TestProject"/>
        <add key="SharePointWebUrl"
             Value="https://google.com/sites/CustomerData/"/>
        <add key="SharePointWebServiceUrl"
             Value="https://google.com/sites/CustomerData/Sharepointvice.asmx"/>
        <add key="Enabled"
             Value="True"/>
    </appSettings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="CommandTimeoutSeconds"
             Value="60"/>
        <add key="ProductList"
             Value="54544,444545,54545245,665656565,5454545,4"/>
        <add key="CustomerIDList"
             Value=""/>
        <add key="DaysBack"
             Value="1"/>
        <add key="PreparedFor"
             Value="Austin"/>
        <add key="Schema"
             Value="Something"/>
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SharePointConnection"
         connectionString="Data Source=CustomerData;Initial Catalog=Userdata; User ID=Userdata; Password=Something123; Integrated Security=False; Connect Timeout=60;"/>
        <add name="ConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=ProductList;Initial Catalog=PDL;User ID=PDLUser;Password=Something123;Integrated Security=False;"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Is there a way I can accomplish the file transformation without going for a new pipeline that alone targets this file. Also, I'm trying to understand the environment if it offer the flexibility to transform any files during the release process, that we can change the values of the parameter in the file, based on the environment, as we do it for the config file using the variable library.

Any responses will be greatly appreciated.